# send message every "x" seconds

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to send messages every 5 seconds on differents numbers with this code:

```
const send_message = ["34123456789","34123456789","34123456789"];

client.on("ready", () => {
   console.log("Client is ready!");
   send_message.map((value) => {
     const chatId = value + "@c.us";
     const message = 'This is a test message';

     client.sendMessage(chatId, message);
   });
});
```

Where or how can I add this code to create a correct bucle?

```
await sleep(5000);
```

Comment: you want that somewhere inside the only "iteration" you've shown, i.e. inside the `.map`? you won't be able to do it inside there ... and why use `.map` when you aren't doing anything with the result of the `.map` ... just use a regular for...of loop and make your `client.on` callback `async`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a for...of loop instead and make the client.on callback `async`

Something like

```
const send_message = ["34123456789", "34123456789", "34123456789"];

client.on("ready", async () => {
  console.log("Client is ready!");

  for (let value of send_message) {
    const chatId = value + "@c.us";
    const message = 'This is a test message';
    client.sendMessage(chatId, message);
    await sleep(5000);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `await` only in an async context. So you can do like this for instance, using `for .. of` instead of `map`

```
client.on("ready", async () => {
  for (let value of send_message) {
    const chatId = value + "@c.us";
    const message = 'This is a test message';    
    client.sendMessage(chatId, message);
    await sleep(5000);
  }
})
```

BTW since node 16 you don't need to create your own `sleep` (or similar) method anymore. You can use `setTimeout` from the [`timers/promises` module](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timerspromisessettimeoutdelay-value-options)